# Where can I change the text displayed by Ubuntu on login?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

When i login into shell in ubuntu 12.04 i can see always this message

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Wed Dec 19 13:41:52

  System load:  0.73               Processes:               133
  Usage of /:   37.5% of 81.73GB   Users logged in:         0
  Memory usage: 3%                 
  Swap usage:   5%                 

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/

Last login: Wed Dec 19 13:36:52 2012 from
```

where can find the script?

Note: I've looked in

- ~/.bashrc
- /etc/profile
- /etc/bash.bashrc
- /etc/profile.d/*

but I have not found it

Comment: `/etc/motd` `/etc/issue` `/etc/issue.net`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three files that can display message for you after login.

Those are:

[/etc/motd](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-message-of-the-day-motd-in-ubuntu-server.html) [ Message Of The Day ]

[/etc/issue](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-login-message/)

[/etc/issue.net](http://linux.die.net/man/5/issue.net)

Comment: thanks. I've looking for `/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo`command